# How can I make a scrolling DIVs background transparent?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a semi-transparent image scroll up to reveal another image below it.

So far, I've got the top image scroll up and the fixed image underneath, but I can't figure out how to get the transparent parts of the top image to show the fixed image underneath.

I've made sure that the top image is transparent and tested it by setting the top slides background color to red, which works fine, but setting it to transparent still shows as white.

In the CSS I've put both of these to no avail:

```
background-color: transparent;

background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong or give me an alternate method to achieve this?

Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/3vw52ncb/2/

Comment: You wrote "I've made sure that the top image is transparent". Isn't this what you didn't manage to do?

Comment: Are you using white background anywhere as its because of white background opacity is not working.

Comment: Your foreground slide is never on top of your background slide because their height adjust so they never overlap. Your transparency is fine it's just that the white color is the page background color - not your pizza as you would like it to be. Look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3vw52ncb/6/ and you'll understand.

Comment: have a play around with the `background-size` property,but this should set you on the way: https://jsfiddle.net/3vw52ncb/8/

Comment: Thanx @jbutler483, i have updated and get the desired result for op, hope so. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/3vw52ncb/9/

Comment: @Leo the lion Could make your comment an answer so I can accept it please? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @BenS-S please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with help of jbutler483's fiddle, i have made what you want. You needed `opacity` to make image transparent and `position: absolute;` to remove white background.

Change your slide1'css with this code :

```
#slide_1 {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/TIaK19Z.png");
  background-size: 120%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;/* To remove white background */
  top: 0;
  opacity:0.8;/* To make the top image transparent */
  left: 0;margin-bottom:100vh;
}
```

you can change the opacity value according to your need.

Tranparent [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/3vw52ncb/12/) and if you want then with white background [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/3vw52ncb/9/)

Comment: Thanks!
My only problem with this is that the top image moves horizontally a bit. Adding `margin: auto 0` fixes this but then also removes vertical scrolling.
Do you know how to center and hide the horizontal scroll bar whilst keeping the vertical one?

Comment: Thanks, I'll fiddle with that and try to get my desired result.

Comment: sure and if get any issue, let me know.

Comment: Do you know how I can get an image to sit on the bottom like in this fiddle? jsfiddle.net/31wdswb6/3